# Crashplan backups after upgrading windows

Tags: windows, upgrade, crashplan

I'm about to upgarde my Vista PC (I know, I know ...) where I have hundreds of GBs stored in crashplan backups. The backup files are located in my "G:" drive so I would like to, after the upgrade is done, remap crashplan so it recognizes them. Any hints ? Thanks.

Comment: Just install the application and map the drive like the first time.  If its the same computer and you are upgrading to say WIndows 7, you won't have to do anything, if the upgrade is supported path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Followed these instructions and worked OK ..

http://support.crashplanpro.com/doku.php/recipe/reconnect_to_an_existing_backup?s%5B%5D=use

Answer (score 0):

Since @xain's link is broken:

1. Upgrade your PC to Windows 7 (or 8 or whatever you're upgrading to)
2. Install Crashplan
3. Tell Crashplan to "adopt" your old computer's backups (It should be an option at the top after you install Crashplan)
4. Tell Crashplan to back up the files again. It doesn't matter if it's at the same location; If your `G:` drive is now your `E:` drive, that's fine. Tell it to back up the `E:` drive then.

Crashplan will then rescan your `E:` drive, and detect that the data already exists in the backup set; it will not back it up twice.